# How can I align items on my website footer

Tags: html, css, wordpress, web, footer

I'm working on the site www.albafitness.com

As you can see, the social media icons and the footer menu are not horizontally aligned. Can someone tell me how to do this please?

Comment: That's not quite how you're supposed to use the site; You are supposed to post what you've tried to show that you are trying and what errors you are getting, then everyone helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you use table for your social icons? It is recommended to use ul tag for things like this.

Try this CSS:

```
.footer_content {
    border-top: 1px solid #1F2024;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 30px 0;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
    width: 940px;
    text-align: center; // Align both elements horizontally
}

table.cnss-social-icon tr td, table.cnss-social-icon, table.cnss-social-icon tr {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent !important;
    border: medium none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    display: inline-block; // inline-block will make it inherit rules from text-align rule
}

.footer_menu {
    padding: 10px 0;
    // float: right; //float will always pull your element to one side. This should be removed.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TO position something, you have three super powers:
1. POSITION ABSOLUTE
2. VERTICAL ALIGN
3. FLOAT

this time we are using no. 1
CSS:

```
.footer_content_wrraper
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="footer_content_wrapper">
....../
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to keep the same html you have, you can just use a negative margin on the menu

```
.footer_menu {margin-top: -21px}
```

but you will need remove it will a media query when you get down to a mobile size. so they don't overlap